# What are positive contributions to SO when you have a ban?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

Suppose my account is banned for questions. I have 2 questions:

1. Is retagging a positive contribution to SO?
2. Is editing a positive contribution to SO?

Comment: They are positive actions if done correctly...

Comment: @Vache - He is asking in context of post ban.

Comment: Which is explained 2 paragraphs down from *`How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?`*

Comment: There are a number of positive things you can do (and if done properly you have identified 2), but the number 1 thing you can do is improve your existing questions

Comment: From the sentence structure (and the look of your profile) I take it you're not currently Q-banned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive contribution will be anything you can still do to make this site better. Thus, retagging will be positive contribution if it's needed. But probably will not change much.

On the other hand, by all means do edit bad content to make it better. Especially **edit your own questions to make them better**. You are banned because you asked many question system considered bad, so making them good is fastest way out of your ban.